# How to check if a database exists in teradata while firing a sqoop import command in shell script?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to fire a sqoop import command from the shell script. It is working fine as expected.

But, if suppose the database is missing in the Teradata then it needs to throw the error and should not go for processing of further commands in the script.

As the syntax is correct, the sqoop import command is returning "0" and it is assuming that the sqoop import command is successful.

How to handle this type of error in the shell script even though the database is missing in the Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you to check if DB exist and/or table and if bteq exit with 1 not to proceed with loading.

```
bteq << eof 

select 1 from DBC.TablesV
where databasename = 'YOUR_DB';
--and TableName = 'YOUR_TABLE'; --Could add and table here.

.if activitycount = 0 then .quit 1
.quit 0

eof
```

Comment: I encountered this problem myself, and the `DBC.TablesV` view can work if the database has tables already. But I found the `DBC.Databases` view to allow for a more general answer, even if your database has no tables: ```sql
SELECT 1 FROM DBC.Databases
WHERE DatabaseName = 'YOUR_DB' ```